# Extending existing .net functionality to iPad

Tags: asp.net, .net, ios, silverlight, ipad

I have this sudden out of the blue requirement for extending a part of a desktop's application functionality to the iOS/iPad platform.

At first I had identified the following possible approach.

1. Recreate/Rewrite the relevant part of the desktop application in Win CF.

This option was a goner from the very onset because the tablet of choice turned out to be an iPad. Of course there is no way (that I know of) of running a Win CF app on iOS/iPhone

The second option was to build a small intranet based web application in asp.net. Now this brings up the following questions.

Q1. Will I require custom third party .net controls specifically designed for browsers that run in an iPhone/iOS?

Q2 Will the application be rendered properly if I use plain asp.net controls? If not, what are the likely problems? (just a quick ballpark explanation)

Any additional insights and help would be of well..great help...as i have not done a lot of mobile applications.`

I intend on finding out the best approach eventually...but any guidance will be invaluable at this stage

Comment: I successfully used MonoTouch to write iPhone apps that made it to the AppStore. Highly recommended IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing extra that you need to do to make the asp.net controls render in an iPad.  The only thing you need to worry about in your user interface design is that anything that relies on a hover, mouseover, or mousemove event will be unusable on a touch device, because touch devices only send click events, or only send other events in conjunction with a click.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Mono.Touch for your .Net needs on iOS](http://xamarin.com/) ?

Note that you will have to re-implement your UI to use the Cocoa touch UI; but it will all be in C#.Net ! You can deploy your app without touching a single line of Objective-C

Now on to your other questions:

> Q1. Will I require custom third party .net controls specifically
>   designed for browsers that run in an iPhone/iOS?

It depends what your application is actually doing. iOS can render HTML content just like any other platform, but you may have to design your page specifically to target their small screen sizes and touch-based navigation. There are a few third party frameworks out there that target HTML 5 and that would definitely help you get started quickly but I would not say you have to use it.

> Q2 Will the application be rendered properly if I use plain asp.net
>   controls? If not, what are the likely problems? (just a quick ballpark
>   explanation)

Given that ASP.Net pages are rendered to HTML before being served to the clients, the iOS will have no trouble rendering it (as far as HTML compliance goes of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to write a web application, you should take a look at MVC4. They've added a lot of tooling for mobile devices, and even have a mobile project template, and jQuery Mobile is baked in.

EDIT: Here's the link to the MVC4 release notes: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes

If you really want to stand up a web application with a small subset of features and minimal effort, and you're sure that it's not going to turn into a full-fledged port, you could give Lightswitch a try. I know it seems silly, but they've now got the ability to publish views as an HTML5 application. I recently did that, and it's stupid simple to point it at the right tables and squirt out a simple HTML view. If the result is good enough for what you need, then it's an easy win and won't chew up a lot of time that might be needed elsewhere.

EDIT: Also the link for the Lightswitch HTML client: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/htmlclient